# Where do I need an SSL certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an app with a separate front end (AngularJS) and back end (Rails). They are hosted in separate AWS elastic beanstalk environments. We have purchased an SSL certificate via AWS which matches the domain name of the front end.

Our app involves completing a survey which includes submitting personal identifiable information.

Do I need an SSL certificate on both the front end and back end? Is it possible to use the same certificate for both? I am new to setting up these types of configurations and internet searches and AWS documentation have not helped.

Comment: Why do you need an Elastic Beanstalk environment to host an AngularJS app? It's just HTML and JavaScript isn't it? Why not host that on S3 for a fraction of the cost?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need an SSL certificate on both the front end and back end?

Yes

> Is it possible to use the same certificate for both?

Yes

You need to request a free SSL certificate for your domain in the Amazon Certificate Management service (ACM). Once you have the certificate you can easily attach it to the load balancers in each of your Elastic Beanstalk environments by adding an HTTPS listener to the load balancers, and selecting the SSL certificate from the list it will present you.

When you request the certificate specify the root domain and a star wildcard for the subdomain. For example if your domain was example.com you would enter `example.com` and `*.example.com` in the SSL certificate request.